# AngularJS: In ng-repeat, assign function output to multiple elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Given that I have a `function GenerateRandomId()`, which returns a new string of some random characters on every call, valid for @id attribute.

How could the following be accomplished?  (NOTE: This code does NOT work)

```
<li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
    {{ randomId = $ctrl.GenerateRandomId() }}
    <input id="{{ randomId }}" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="{{ randomId }}">...</label>
</li>

//in the controller
var self = this;
self.GenerateRandomId = function () {
  return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10);
};
```

### Edit

1. Removed "var" in front of `randomId`.
2. Provided `GenerateRandomId()` function inside of the controller.

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking at trying to create unique ids for your inputs... can you instead do something like `id="someSection_{{ $index }}"`?

Comment: Not really. This is a part of a component which could be reused on the same page.  Chances are I will get multiple identical outputs from someSection_{{ $index }} throughout the page.  Thanks.

Comment: So you're creating a directive, what about generating a unique prefix within the directive and using `id="{{directivePrefix}}_{{$index}}"`?

Comment: remove var from html

Comment: i agree with McAden, a directive would be the angular way of solving it.

Comment: @McAden - Could you explain more or provide a code sample?  Sorry, I'm far from an Angular expert.

Comment: Hi there. Just to note to say there's no need to add thanks or other chatty material to posts (advance thanks, hopes people can help, salutations, regards, theistic invocations, etc). The [reference discussion on Meta is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it). Technical writing is encouraged here, as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

remove "var" from html code.
try below code

```
<li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
{{ randomId = GenerateRandomId() }}
<input id="{{ randomId }}" type="checkbox" />
<label for="{{ randomId }}">...</label>
</li>
```

Comment: You may want to actually change the given code and keep its format :D

Comment: Removing "var" results in Error: [$rootScope:infdig].  I actually tried it before posting the question.

Comment: Can you provide GenerateRandomId() function as my code is working

Comment: @Sunil - I edited the question.  Provided GenerateRandomId() function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it. You can declare the function and add it to `data-id` and `for`.

```js
var random = angular.module("random", []);

var ctrl = random.controller("Ctrl", Ctrl);

function Ctrl() {
  var self = this;
  self.number = "";
  self.items = [1, 2, 3];

  self.randomIntegersGenerator = function(){
        var randomNumbers = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < self.items.length; i++ ){
            randomNumbers[i] = randomId();
        }
     return randomNumbers;

  }
  self.randomIntegers = self.randomIntegersGenerator();
 }

 function randomId() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="random">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl">
    <li ng-repeat="random in ctrl.randomIntegers">
     
     
      <input data-id= {{random}}  type="checkbox" />
      <label for= {{random}} >Something</label>
      {{random}}
      
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, 2 problems here.  1.  {{ ctrl.number = ctrl.randomId()}} outputs the random value in front of the checkbox, which is undesirable.  2. If I click on "Run code snippet" button below the answer, I get Error: [$rootScope:infdig]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items" ng-init="randomId = $ctrl.GenerateRandomId()">
    <input id="{{ randomId }}" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="{{ randomId }}">...</label>
</li>
```